# Python Запрос и анализ данных с сайта

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

Я в этом вопросе абсолютный новичок. Задание, кажется, простое для тех, кто в этом разбирается, но я никак подойти к решению не могу, рецепты из интернета приводят мой пайчарм к ошибкам, в общем, задания:

1. Написать программу, которая на основании запроса с сайта http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp определит курс гонконгского доллара к российскому рублю.
2. Написать программу, которая на основании запроса к https://openweathermap.org выведет среднюю и максимальную температуру(morn) температура в вашем городе (в запросе можно указать широту и долготу инд города) за предстоящие 5 дней(вкл сегодняшний) в градусах Цельсия. Подобный запрос потребует регистрации на данном ресурсе с использованием бесплатного плана (free).

Может сможете подсказать в какую сторону рыть и что читать.

Comment: Попробуйте `pandas.read_html`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: С XML будет сложнее... Надо смотреть, пробовать всякое

Comment: Про openweathermap на stackoverflow беглый поиск показывает 98 вопросов. Большинство - с примерами кода. Почитайте их.

Comment: > Подобный запрос потребует регистрации... - вам нужно при каждом запуске парсера регистрировать новый аккаунт или логиниться в уже созданный?

Comment: А в целом - ваш вопрос слишком общий. Приводите конкретные примеры "рецептов из интернета", которые у вас не работают, и полный текст ошибок, которые у вас с этими рецептами возникают, будем разбираться.

Comment: @Стас Логиниться в созданный, думаю

Comment: @Xander Да, спасибо за наводку, гляну. Что касается ошибок, то я элементарно, не могу запустить такой код:
```import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html("https://webapps.sandiego.gov/sdfiredispatch/", header=0)
print(tables)```

Comment: @AlexK нужно парсить сайт через `requests/bs4` или можно пользоваться api? Для сайта погоды

Comment: @Стас
Ну вот это да!! :) Огромное Вам спасибо! Вам бы учебники писать и статьи публиковать. Классно все написано, очень понятно и доступно.
Конечно, буду разбираться и читать (отдельно спасибо за ссылку на документацию, обязательно почитаю) 
Круто, нет слов))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу скажу, сделал без `pandas`.

---

Сначала первая задача:

> Написать программу, которая на основании запроса с сайта http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp определит курс гонконгского доллара к российскому рублю.

Сайт даёт ответ в формате `xml`, значит `lxml` нам в руки, и вперёд!

```
import requests # pip install requests
from lxml import etree # pip install lxml
    
xml_response = etree.fromstring(requests.get("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp").text.encode("1251"))
curs = xml_response.find("Valute[@ID='R01200']/Value").text

print(f"Один Гонконгский доллар равен {curs} рублей")
```

Получаем ответ от сайта, и декодируем текст в байты, по кодировке *Windows-1251*. Зачем? Сайт возвращает `xml` в данной кодировке, и `lxml` отказывается работать с ним напрямую, нужно переводить в байты.

Далее получаем этот блок по *ID*:

```xml
<Valute ID="R01200">
  <NumCode>344</NumCode>
  <CharCode>HKD</CharCode>
  <Nominal>1</Nominal>
  <Name>Гонконгский доллар</Name>
  <Value>10,1304</Value>
</Valute>
```

и из него - значение поля `Value`.

Вот и всё, получаем в виде текста и можно выводить на консоль!

---

Вторая задача:

> Написать программу, которая на основании запроса к https://openweathermap.org выведет среднюю и максимальную температуру(`morn`) в вашем городе за предстоящие 5 дней(включая сегодняшний) в градусах Цельсия.

Вы мне так и не ответили, можно ли использовать *API*, поэтому я сделал с его использованием (так гораздо проще).

Регистрируетесь на сайте, получаете свой *api ключ*. Я использовал `One Call API`, можете почитать [документацию](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api)

Быстро объясню, как пользоваться:

1. Оправляем запрос *API*:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={latitude}&lon={longitude}&exclude=minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric
```

- `latitude` - широта, `longitude` - долгота
- `API key` - ваш *api* ключ.
- `exclude` - данные, которые нужно исключить из запроса. (подробнее в документации)

(в представленном выше запросе мы получаем погоду в Москве на сегодняшний, и ещё 7 дней вперёд, в метрической системе. Исключаем минутный и часовой прогнозы, и предупреждения спецслужб.)

2. Парсим полученный `JSON` (получаем из него температуру для текущего и четырёх последующих дней).
3. Считаем и выводим результат

```py
import requests
import json

API_KEY = "You API key"

longitude = 37.6156  # долгота
latitude  = 55.7522  # широта

temperature_arr = []

api_response = requests.get(f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={latitude}&lon={longitude}&exclude=minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric").text
json_response = json.loads(api_response)
for i in range(5):    
    temperature_arr.append(json_response["daily"][i]["temp"]["morn"])
    

print("Средняя температура за пять дней равна", sum(temperature_arr) / 5,
      "\nМаксимальная температура за пять дней равна", max(temperature_arr))
```

В качестве места для получения данных о погоде я выбрал Москву.

С помощью модуля `JSON` парсим ответ (температура за утро (вы сказали брать из поля `morn`) находится по пути `daily/day_index/temp/morn`).

Также в этом `JSON` есть погода на текущий день (`current`), но гораздо удобнее использовать по индексам (в данном случае).

В конце просто считаем среднее арифметическое и максимум, выводим на консоль.

---

Вот и всё!

<sub>Надеюсь, вам поможет и вы разберётесь, а не просто скопипасите `:)`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Еще вот так сделал первую задачу - немного попроще.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp').text.split("</Valute>")
NAME = 'Гонконгский доллар'

for n in r:
    if n.count(NAME):
        nominal = (int(n[n.find('<Nominal>') + len('<Nominal>'):n.find('</Nominal>')]))
        value = (float(n[n.find('<Value>') + len('<Value>'):n.find('</Value>')].replace(',', '.')))
        print(f"{nominal} {NAME} равен {value} рублей")
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так решила с помощью модуля urllib.request

```
import urllib.request
from xml.dom import minidom

source = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp ")
xmldoc = minidom.parse(source)
list_ids = ['R01200']
valutes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Valute")
for valute in valutes:
    id = valute.getAttribute("ID")
    value = valute.getElementsByTagName("Value")[0]
    char_code = valute.getElementsByTagName("CharCode")[0]
    if id in list_ids:
        print(f"char code:{char_code.firstChild.data}, money exchange:{value.firstChild.data} ")
        quit()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]